# C# - Finding "insufficient data for an image" error in PDF

Tags: c#, itext

I have few PDFs which are someway corrupted. Whenever I open them physically I get the error -

> Insufficient data for an image

Now, I have a solution to this problem. But to apply that solution from code, I need to identify those corrupted PDFs from the code. Is there any way to identify from the code if a PDF is having the ***"Insufficient data for an image"*** error?

Here is the link for the PDF. Please use Adobe Reader to see the issue -
https://sendeyo.com/en/01f8eb078c

Comment: Please specify the reason for downvote.

Comment: What happens when you try to open the corrupted pdf files via code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I am able to read the PDF properly. No exception occurs.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: @mkl done. shared.

Comment: This seems difficult to track. Still any luck?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, this means the size of the Image XObject stream is too small given the properties of the image like the Height, Width, BitsPerComponent, and ColorSpace.

To detect this scenario in a programmatic fashion you would need to open the stream and read it's decoded size. Then calculate what the size should be based on the above mentioned attributes. Comparing these two values should indicate when there is insufficient data in the image stream.